# Why does whatsapp prompt me to rescan qr code on the desktop app?

Tags: whatsapp, windows-10

I am using the WhatsApp for Desktop app on my Windows 10 PC. It prompts me to rescan the QR code every time my phone's display turns off - this is in spite of the fact that I checked the 'keep me signed in' box on the desktop app before scanning the QR code.

Data saver and battery saver are turned off. I have also explicitly allowed in battery saver for whatsapp to run in the background. I am connected to a wifi network (with my pc being on the same network) and have a celluar connection.

My phone is the 640 LTE with Windows Phone 8.1 Update 2.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to simply be a bug in the Windows Phone version of WhatsApp. I've observed the same problem. It's probably not hard to fix - the app is either not saving the associated client correctly or is not retrieving it when it wakes up - but for now I don't actually have a fix. You could try bugging WhatsApp about it, but they may not care given that the OS is end-of-life.